# Multiple where clauses vs. 'and' in kusto

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

In terms of performance, is the following query

```
ResourceEvents
| where ResourceType == "Foo" and EventType == "Bar"
```

practically the same as

```
ResourceEvents
| where ResourceType == "Foo"
| where EventType == "Bar"
```

Or are the records filtered sequentially, performing two searches instead of one combined?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

both options are equivalent in terms of semantics and performance

Answer (score 7):

Adding to Yoni's answer, you can check it yourself by looking at the query plan.

```
.show queryplan  <|
StormEvents
| where State == "TEXAS" and EventType == "Flood"


.show queryplan  <|
StormEvents
| where State == "TEXAS" 
| where EventType == "Flood"
```

The plans are equivalent.

Comment: Is there documentation for `.show queryplan`, I can't find it https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/search/?scope=kusto&terms=queryplan

Answer (score 0):

In your exact scenario, it seems to be equivalent; but if you have heavy parsing, better use chained `| where`  clause compare to a `| where ... and ....`
Maybe have a look at [kql query best practices](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/best-practices) > 'Lookup for rare keys/values in dynamic object'.

Thanks @sheldonzy! I didn't knew about `.show queryplan`. It seems to not be available when using log analytics sadly; but some testing can be achieved by running queries on [Microsoft test ADX](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples) which is freely available.