# In Kusto, is there any difference in performance when using nested 'where' vs 'and'

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

Semantically these two queries are identical:

```
mytable
| where predicate1
| where predicate2
```

```
mytable
| where predicate1 and predicate2
```

Is there any difference performance-wise? Does the optimizer reduce #1 to #2 under the hood?

Comment: Please see a similar post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72407993/multiple-where-clauses-vs-and-in-kusto/72408195#72408195)